# В приложении java spring boot , html не загружает функцию из js файла

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

У меня есть html-файл, в нем кнопка, которая должна вызывать функцию из js-файла, но она не вызывается.

**HTML файл:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/auth.js" th:inline="javascript"></script>

<button onclick="btnOpenModal()">open modal</button>


<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
 <h2>Registration</h2>
 <p>FORM</p>
 <button>SUBMIT</button>
</dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS файл:**

```
function btnOpenModal() {
    console.log("HELLO")
}
```

**Структура файлов:** [image: клик]

**Ошибка в браузере:** [image: клик]

Comment: Скорее всего у вас js не загрузился. Проверьте в косоли разработчика вкладку сеть. Сморите на пути загрузки, возможно путь стоит указать как `./js/auth.js`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CNRYQg3

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить в SecurityConfig `http.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()`